# Google スプレッドシート の条件付き書式で「背景色」と「文字色」を別々に満たしたい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Google スプレッドシート の条件付き書式で「背景色」と「文字色」を別々に満たしたいです。

具体的には、添付画像のような設定で、
「背景は青、文字色は赤」にしたいのですが、
「背景は白、文字色は赤」になってしまいます。

[image]

Answer (score 0):

自分で同じような件があったときは、面倒ですが、
背景は青、文字色は赤の条件のように、全パターンを設定しました。
質問の件だと以下な感じでしょうか。
`=AND($H9<$D9, $I9=1)`

あと Google には改善要望を出す機能があるので、
こういったものは複合条件で書式が適用されるよう、
要望を出したほうが良いと思います。

Comment: やはり、それしかないですかね。ありがとうございます。